# Angular interfaces -- inserting object to a nested array ( Cannot read properties of undefined)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, interface

I want to push object to subCategory which is an array under ITemplate interface but I am receiving error  `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subCategory')` .

How do i push an object to subCategory array?

Any idea guys how to make this possible and what causes the error ?

Thanks, appreciated.

#ts code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'

interface ITemplate {
  id: number;
  entitlement: string;
  required: boolean;
  isHeaderCategory: boolean;
  subCategory: ITemplate2[]
}


interface ITemplate2 {
  id: number;
  sub_name: string;
}

const mockData: ITemplate[] = []

@Component({
  selector: 'app-template',
  templateUrl: './template.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./template.component.css'],
})
export class TemplateComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('thiss' , this.templates)
  }

  add() {
    this.templates[0].subCategory.push({
      id: 0,
      sub_name: 'test'
    }) 
  }

  templates: ITemplate[] = mockData
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access `this.templates` `0th` element and inside that element you are trying to push into subCategory, but first you should have 0th element in first place for `this.templates`.

try this.

```
add() {

    this.templates.push({
                     id:1,
                    entitlement: 'string related to entitlement',
                    required: true;
                    isHeaderCategory: false;
                    subCategory: []
                   });
    this.templates[0].subCategory.push({
      id: 0,
      sub_name: 'test'
    }) ;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are trying to push an item to an array position/index that doesn't exist, hence the error.
the variable **templates** which is an array is of length 0.
In order to be able to do what you want to do, the variable **templates** must have values.